# What are some good resources on Bayesian unconditional power analysis, besides John Uebersax's article?

Tags: bayesian, references, statistical-power

I refer to the article "[Bayesian Unconditional Power Analysis](https://john-uebersax.com/stat/bpower.htm)" by John S. Uebersax (2007).

I'd like to explore the subject further. I haven't checked yet the references that the Uebersax's article mentions, but I was wondering it there are other good references or resources about the subject.

I'm looking preferably, but not necessarily, for resources that use numerical examples, to check if I do not misinterpret some formulas or algorithms.

Comment: I never got around to reading [Grieve's book](https://www.routledge.com/Hybrid-FrequentistBayesian-Power-and-Bayesian-Power-in-Planning-Clinical/Grieve/p/book/9781032111292) but it seems to cover this topic quite extensively.

Comment: @PBulls From the summary, it looks exactly like what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: @PBulls, this should be an answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure (not having read it) but I'll add it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Andrew P. Grieve's [Hybrid Frequentist/Bayesian Power and Bayesian Power in Planning Clinical Trials](https://www.routledge.com/Hybrid-FrequentistBayesian-Power-and-Bayesian-Power-in-Planning-Clinical/Grieve/p/book/9781032111292) (2022), it contains several worked examples of various Bayesian and hybrid approaches to determining power/assurance in clinical trials.

(disclaimer: I followed his workshop but didn't actually read the book)

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t exactly what you requested but is one of the best examples of unconditional decision making for stopping a sequential study that I have ever seen, due to David Spiegelhalter.  His method uses only observables to decide whether it is futile to continue a study. See [this](https://hbiostat.org/bayes/bet/design#sequential-monitoring-and-futility-analysis) from which the graph is reproduced below.

[image: Probability of ultimate success]